# Interactive Canvas is terminated when I call an app that is not in the phone

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using Interactive Canvas.

I made a link to Instagram and Youtube Android App, which works when the phone has the app, but the link directly to the app shuts down AoG if the phone doesn't have one.

If the phone doesn't have the app, you want the action to go to the app page in Google Play, but nothing happens when the AoG that was displaying the web app ends.

Is there a way to keep AoG from turning off when there is no app?

Here is the code that I used.

```
function datalink(data) {
    let linkURL;
    switch (data) {
        case ("Instagram"):
            let instaTag = linkKeyword.split(' ')[0];
            // linkURL = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/";
            linkURL = "instagram://tag?name="+instaTag;
            break;
        case ("Youtube"):
            // linkURL = "https://m.youtube.com/results?search_query=";
            linkURL = "vnd.youtube://m.youtube.com/results?search_query="+linkKeyword;
            break;
    }
    window.location.href=linkURL; // external link
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using those URL patterns are specific to specific apps that register those intents. If you want to ensure that your links can work when the app is not installed, you can use a regular HTTP URL such as `http://instagram.com`.

Many apps register their own URL patterns so that opening instagram.com will redirect the user to the app. But if the app is not installed then it can use the website as a fallback mechanism.

Comment: I've tried the HTTP URL, but it doesn't work with Interactive Canvas. The URL causes net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE error. 
As expected, that Youtube/Instagram URL should go to the webpage, but Both connected to the error page. 

What I want is to run the Android app, and if the phone don't have one, I want to send to Google Play.